# Getting Referential integrity constraint violation while one findBy Query is getting executed

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I have an annotation over the method: updateBreadCrumbTranscation2

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)

```
    updateBreadCrumbTranscation2(Environment environment, DeployedComponent currentDeployedComponent,
                Map<ComponentId, Component> availableComponentsMap){
              // code snnipet .. invoking other methods
                evaluateConditionalDependencies();
    
    }
   
evaluateConditionalDependencies( breadCrumbSoftwareDTO, environment, obsoleteComponentCandidates ){
//code snipppets 
     BreadCrumbComponent breadCrumbComponent = ( (BreadCrumbComponent) breadCrumbManagerMap.get( DCConstants.COMPONENTS ) );
                for ( DeployedComponent deployedComponent : environment.getActiveDeployedComponents() )
                {
                    breadCrumbComponent.evaluateConditionalDependencies( environment, deployedComponent,
                            breadCrumbComponent.getAvailableComponentsMap( environment ) );
            }
   //code snipppets 
}
```

Now this method **evaluateConditionalDependencies** has below line which is executing findBy Query.

```
public void evaluateConditionalDependencies( Environment environment, DeployedComponent currentDeployedComponent,
            Map<ComponentId, Component> availableComponentsMap ){
 if{  
dependentComponents = deployedComponentRepository
                         .findByObsoletedFalseAndComponentNameAndEnvironmentEnvId( dependencyCompName, environment.getEnvId() );
}
else{
dependentComponents = deployedComponentRepository
                         .findByObsoletedFalseAndComponentNameAndEnvironmentEnvId( dependencyCompName, environment.getEnvId() );
}
...
//code snippets
activeDeployedComponent.getConnectionInfosForDeployedComp().removeAll( connectionInfoToBeRemoved ); 

environment.getDeployedComponents().removeAll( componentDependencies );
}
```

However because of for loop there are 2 other jpa methods which is deleting data from "ConnectionInfo" and "DeployedCOmponents" Table before findBy is getting executed.

So, due to for loop, it is executing again for other components where it is trying to execute findBy Query and once this particular line is getting executed, I'm getting the below error.

**My Analysis are below:
Basically I have 2 tables: a) ConnectionInfo b)Deployed_Component c) Component and it is trying to fecth the data from Deployed_Component as the method name suggest "findByObsoletedFalseAndComponentNameAndEnvironmentEnvId" but here it self Error has been thrown**

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "deployed_component", catalog = "deploy_center")
    public class DeployedComponent extends AbstractBean
    {
    // Multiple lines of code
     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "ENV_ID", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk__deployed_component__environment__env_id"))
        public Environment getEnvironment()
        {
            return this.environment;
        }

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ENV_ID", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk__deployed_component__environment__env_id"))
    public Environment getEnvironment()
    {
        return this.environment;
    }


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MACHINE_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk__deployed_component__machine__machine_id"))
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    public Machine getMachine()
    {
        return this.machine;
    }
    }

Component.java:
class Component{
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "component_artifact_type", catalog = "deploy_center", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "DEPLOYABLE_COMP_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "ARTIFACT_TYPE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    public Set<ArtifactType> getArtifactTypes()
    {
        return this.artifactTypes;
    }
}
```

Java class: ConnectionInfo:

```
ConnectionInfo{
            @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPLOYED_COMP", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk__connection_info__deployed_component__deployed_comp"))
    public DeployedComponent getDeployedComponentByDeployedComp()
    {
        return this.deployedComponentByDeployedComp;
    }
}
```

Class: Environment.java

```
//code snippet
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "environment", orphanRemoval = true)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    public Set<DeployedComponent> getDeployedComponents()
    {
        return this.deployedComponents;
    }
```

Below is the Error message:

```
    WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:137 - SQL Error: 23503, SQLState: 23503
    2024-02-05 19:53:19 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:142 - Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK__CONNECTION_INFO__DEPLOYED_COMPONENT__DEPLOYED_COMP: DEPLOY_CENTER.CONNECTION_INFO FOREIGN KEY(DEPLOYED_COMP) 
    REFERENCES DEPLOY_CENTER.DEPLOYED_COMPONENT(DEPLOYED_COMPONENT_ID) (CAST(258 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement:
    delete from deploy_center.deployed_component where DEPLOYED_COMPONENT_ID=? [23503-212]
    2024-02-05 19:53:19 
    **INFO  AbstractBatchImpl:208 - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements**
    2024-02-05 19:53:20 ERROR QuickDeployConfigService:137 - DCXXE000could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["FK__CONNECTION_INFO__DEPLOYED_COMPONENT__DEPLOYED_COMP: DEPLOY_CENTER.CONNECTION_INFO FOREIGN KEY(DEPLOYED_COMP) REFERENCES DEPLOY_CENTER.DEPLOYED_COMPONENT(DEPLOYED_COMPONENT_ID) (CAST(258 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement:
    delete from deploy_center.deployed_component where DEPLOYED_COMPONENT_ID=? [23503-212]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    2024-02-05 19:53:20 ERROR GlobalExceptionHandler:137 - org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a];
```

PS: I have Edited this Question for Better Understanding. I hope it might be clear, if not please let me know I your concerns.
Really Appreciate your Efforts

Comment: Please format your messages

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You should post minimal code that reproduces the error you're seeing

Comment: Yeah I just added the @Transactional which may help you and others to understand what is being used in the code. Could you please answer if you got the Question

Comment: added `@Transactional` to what? Please read the article I linked and familiarize yourself with the requirements for asking questions on this site. Thank you.

Comment: @Quassnoi, I hope now it is clear to you

Comment: Are you removing an element from a one-to-many list/collection? It looks like a cascade operation (delete from ...) is triggered by your findBy query which could mean JPA is trying to refresh an entity and thus executing cascades. If you post Environment, ConnectionInfo and DeployedComponent classes in detail I might be able to give a better answer.

Comment: "...and it is trying to fecth the data from" -- It's not trying to fecth; it's trying to DELETE. The error clearly says: `delete from deploy_center.deployed_component where DEPLOYED_COMPONENT_ID=?`.

Comment: @RahulKumar: it's not. I have no idea what `findByObsoletedFalseAndComponentNameAndEnvironmentEnvId` does.

Comment: @BahattinUngormus, True that Error says it is trying to delete the record .. But when I was debugging line by line what I found is when it was executing findByObsoletedFalseAnd .. it never come back either with List or Empty. Suddenly I got the above pasted Error. I'm not sure from where delete from is getting triggered. For more info I'm adding other classes as well

Comment: @BahattinUngormus Thank you very much for your inputs, BTW I have update some information after seeing your answer. Could you please look once and let me know what  Could be the best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate (or other similar JPA implementations) do not immediately execute queries. Instead the queries are executed either on transaction completion or when the updated/deleted entities are queried. The delete operation you see in the error was actually called before you call findBy method. When you call findBy method the resulting query needs a fresh version of the entities related to an entity you deleted before, thus it triggers a session flush.

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/flushing/Flushing.html).

> By default, Hibernate uses the AUTO flush mode which triggers a flush in the following circumstances:
>
> prior to committing a Transaction
>
> prior to executing a JPQL/HQL query that overlaps with the queued entity actions
>
> before executing any native SQL query that has no registered synchronization

Hence, in your case I make the following assumptions:

You have an Environment entity, lets call it `env`.

You remove one o more elements from the collection `env.deployedComponents` which marks the `DeployedComponent` entities you removed for deletion. This happens because you set `orphanRemoval=true` in your Environment class's `getDeployedComponents` one-to-many mapping.

Before the transaction completes you call your `findBy...` method which *eventually* queries some DeployedComponent entities.

This query requires fresh `DeployedComponent` entities, so it flushes the session and thus executes delete since you added **CASCADE_ALL** option in your `getDeployedComponents` one-to-many mapping.

A simple way to solve this would be changing `orphanRemoval` to `false` and/or removing **CASCADE_ALL** option from your `deployedComponents` mapping in `Environment` class. However, this can cause other complications, so be sure to test it throughly.

Comment: What should I add instead of  CASCADE_ALL ?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to change CASCADE option. Removing 'orphanRemoval' option might be enough for your case.

Comment: looks like your Solution worked for me but We can't   orphanRemoval= false in our case, that is what I got the suggestion from Our Senior, But still not sure how to fix this

Comment: It is suggest to me that we can't make it OrphanRemoval=False.  What else can be Done. The Strange part is When I'm trying to Access the data base There is records seen for Deployed_Comp=258, But still I'm getting this Error. Could it be the case that H2 Data Base is inConsistance because I have tested it more than 10 times and I couldn't find the data.